# windows 7 choose profile on startup?

Tags: windows-7

I have windows 7 and 'windows 7 patched' profiles of my operating system. I'm trying to boot into 'windows 7 patched' profile, yet the os boots into the windows 7 profile without giving me a choice. The patched profile is set as the default profile yet nothing is changed. How do I forcefully select the desired profile on start up of windows? F8 on start up?

Answer (score 1):

Use `MSCONFIG` to confirm your "Windows 7 patched" is mark as `Default OS`, if you had never tried to boot in to "Windows 7 patched" and you are assuming that SHOULD work, you may also adjust the `Timeout` seconds to 30 to ensure you can manually select the "Windows 7 patched" for testing purpose.

MSCONFIG screenshot:

[image]